# BeautifulSoup drops children when parent is in an implied namespace

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am building a screenscraper for Nordstrom's website using selenium and BeautifulSoup.  The website does not actually have every tag in a namespace, but the Firefox webdriver creates one to avoid ambiguity (specifically, the site has a `<html xmlns>` tag that seems to confuse the driver).
Thus, everything is put in the namespace `a0`.  However, Beautiful Soup only returns the parent element and (sometimes) one level of children when `find()` is called.
Take this html for example:

```
<div class='division'>
   <a href='#'>
      <img />
   </a>
</div>
```

Everything is in the implied `a0` namespace, so we can get the image with:

```
soup.find('a0:div',{'class':'division'}).find('a0:img')
```

However, this returns `None`.  I have looked through `soup.prettify()` and can say with certainty that the `a0:img` is within the `a0:div`.  Is this an intended feature (in which case I need to find a new way of doing it) or a bug (in which case I need a workaround)?

**EDIT**:

To avoid confusion, this is an example demonstrating the entire workflow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup # Note that this is BeautifulSoup 3
b = webdriver.Firefox()
b.get("http://shop.nordstrom.com/c/womens-skirts")
borscht = BeautifulSoup(b.page_source)
theImageThatCannotBeFound = borscht.find('a0:div',{'class':'fashion-item'}).find('a0:img')
```

The above code sets `theImageThatCannotBeFound` to `None`, which I believe is incorrect.  I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Note that `soup.find('a0:div',{'class':'division'})` returns the `div` but without the image (or any other second level children).

Comment: Can you provide a specific url?

Comment: http://shop.nordstrom.com/c/womens-skirts for example

Comment: That specific url does not contain a `<div class="division">`. In fact, a simple search of the page's source finds no instance of the string 'division' at all.

Comment: And you should probably assume I was giving an example of a similar situation.  Try this one instead:
`soup.find('a0:div',{'class':'fashion-item'}).find('a0:img')`

Comment: If you want me to generalize this as little as possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23741/discussion-between-astex-and-that1guy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://shop.nordstrom.com/c/womens-skirts'
fp = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

print soup.find('div',{'class':'fashion-item'}).findAll('img') # also tried .find
```

Try excluding`a0:`. That's what seems to be your problem.

EDIT:

Using both Chrome and Firefox browsers in and out of Selenium, `xmlns` is set to an empty string when I view it, which is why the above code works for me. It seems that by mismatch of some component somewhere, we're not getting the same results, and you're getting the namespace `a0:`.

Because I cannot reproduce the situation, the only solution I can find (albeit very hacky), is to manually replace the namespace:

```
source = browser.page_source.replace('a0:div','div')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)

print soup.find('div',{'class':'fashion-item'}).find('img')
```

I'll admit its not exactly an ideal solution. I'll keep looking and update my answer if I find a more elegant fix.

Comment: Note that this must be done in Selenium to correctly parse javascript.

Comment: urllib parses the html in a different way than selenium.webdriver.Firefox, which is what I use here.  I _do_ mention that I use selenium in the question.

Comment: I'm guessing arbitrarily that the a0 namespace has something to do with firebug.  Either way, manually removing the namespace via string manipulation seems to work (I just replaced 'a0:' with '' everywhere ignoring any effects that might have on the content).